# Using window.location.href to redirect user when he selects option in select box only changes last bit of the url in navigator

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, select

In all of my rails app pages, I have a select box that changes depending on circumstances :

```
<% if session[:user_status]%>
    <% if params[:office_id] %>
      <%= select_tag "dash_select", options_for_select([["<i class='fa fa-lock select_icon' aria-hidden='true'></i>"+session[:user_status], session[:user_status]], ["all offices", "all"]]), class: "form-control custom-office-select wide main-select-bar" %>
    <% elsif params[:account_asso_id] %>
      <%= select_tag "dash_select", options_for_select([["<i class='fa fa-lock select_icon' aria-hidden='true'></i>"+session[:user_status], session[:user_status]], ["<i class='fa fa-globe' aria-hidden='true'></i>
all offices", "all"]], "all"), class: "form-control custom-office-select wide"  %>
    <% else %>
      <%= select_tag "dash_select", options_for_select([["<i class='fa fa-lock select_icon' aria-hidden='true'></i>"+session[:user_status], session[:user_status]], ["<i class='fa fa-globe select_icon' aria-hidden='true'></i>all offices", "all"]], session[:user_status]), class: "form-control custom-office-select wide"  %>
    <% end -%>
  <% elsif session[:user_status] %>
    <%= select_tag "dash_select", options_for_select([session[:user_status], session[:user_status]]), class: "form-control" %>
  <% else %>
  <% end -%>
```

I have written some JS that is triggered when options of the select box are selected : I redirect the user to a different page depending on which option was selected.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select').niceSelect();
      $("#dash_select").change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == "all") {
              window.location.href = "association/account_assos/"+<%=session[:account_asso_id]%>+"/offices"
            }
        else if ($(this).val() == "admin"){
              window.location.href = "association/account_assos/"+<%=session[:account_asso_id]%>
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == "employee"){
          window.location.href = "/users/"+ <%=session[:user_id] %>
        }
        else {
              var office_id = $(this).val();
              window.location.href = "association/office/"+office_id;
        }
      });
    });
```

When I change the selected option in the select box, the url in the navigator is indeed changed but instead of changing the whole url and simply building on top of "http://localhost:3000/" for example, it is suppressing the last / bit of the current url and building with the new url on top of it.

For instance if the url of the page I'm currently on is :
"http://localhost:3000/association/account_assos/6/users"
and let's say I change my select to "admin", it will get rid of the "/users" part of the current url and build on top of it..which gives me :
http://localhost:3000/association/account_assos/6/association/account_assos/<%=session[:account_asso_id]%>

How can I change the whole url and not only the last bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using a relative path. Either change the URL string you provide to be absolute, or precede it with a `/` to make it relative to the base folder.

Also note that `switch` statement may also be more fitting with the pattern you're using. Try this:

```
$("#dash_select").change(function() {
    var url;
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case: 'all':
            url = "/association/account_assos/<%= session[:account_asso_id] %>"; 
            break;
        case: 'admin':
            url = "/association/account_assos/<%= session[:account_asso_id] %>";
            break;
        case: 'employee':
            url = "/users/<%= session[:user_id] %>";
            break;
        default:
            url = "/association/office/" + $(this).val();                
    }
    window.location.assign(url);
});
```